# Groovy map compare key from one test step and value of another test step and assert if it's true or false

Tags: java, dictionary, groovy, soapui

I have groovy script like this:

```
def map = ['Response' : 'id']

def p1 = context.testCase.testSteps["TestStep_1"].properties
def p2 = context.testCase.testSteps["TestStep_2"].properties

def result = []

def assertPropertyValue = { p1key, p2key -> 
    def temp = p1[p1key].value == p2[p2key].value
    log.info("Comparing $p1key, and $p2key values respectively ${p1[p1key].value} == ${p2[p2key].value} ? $temp")
    temp
}
map.each { result << assertPropertyValue(it.key, it.value) }
assert result.each{it.value == true}, 'Comparison failed, check log'
```

My groovy script does not assert false despite value of TestScript_2 does not match with key from TestStep_1.
I get the following log:

```
Fri Aug 12 17:48:16 CEST 2022:INFO:Comparing Response, and id values respectively {"code":"200","timestamp":"Fri Aug 12 15:12:45 UTC 2022","HttpStatus":"OK","id":"8154b2d1-4f83-4b2c-b100-5dab36b37ab6"} == 929c2a62-5c8a-4e85-bf65-776696503818 ? false
```

IDs does not match and I will expect my groovy test case to assert with "'Comparison failed, check log'".
Do you have any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

`each` on a `List` in groovy return a `List` so since your `result` object is not `null` neither empty, then your assert always returns `true`.

If you want to check that there is no `false` value inside `result` list, try with [`any`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#any(groovy.lang.Closure)):

```
assert !result.any{ it.value == false }, 'Comparision failed, check log'
```

Alternatively you can use `find` as @dagget suggest in his answer, however since `find` returns the object found or `null` it could be necessary an extra comparission to help `assert` to discern bettwen boolean object `false` and `null`. Using `find`:

```
assert result.find { it.value == false } == null, 'Comparision failed, check log'
```

Comment: Ok its asserting but its also asserting in case when two are the same. I would like to assert when IDs are different but to pass when IDs are identical.

Comment: @gibb IMO the problem is not with the assert you can check it with list of booleans and see that it works correctly, the problem is that you're not comparing the ID fields between them.  Check `result` list before the assert, it always be filled with `false`.